# ERPNEXT 14 chart of accounts

Tags: erpnext

Can someone help me create a chart of accounts for ERPnext 14. I am not very good with the accounting setup. Have only one BANK and 4 investors. Also want to add opening balances. Any help is really appreciated.

I have tried following the tutorial but still very confused.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The issue is not with the code. I am not able to understand the process to create the chart of account and opening balances of the bank.